# SWIFT parsing issues

Tags: arrays, json, swift, utf-8

I am new to SWIFT.

I want to parse Json in SWIFT but when I add jsonresult as an array values added without UTF8StringConversion but when I convert then I am unable to add it to array in sWIFT

how can I parse this data and get array of dictionary with UTF8StringEncoding.

```
[
  {
    "id": "56556523d035cafbdb5dae19",
    "club_name": "Tallkrogens IF",
    "image_url": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/openratio-client-sportway/561ceb8b68dd3.jpeg"
  },
  {
    "id": "56556523d035cafbdb5dae1a",
    "club_name": "Team Kedde FK",
    "image_url": "testing url"
  },
  {
    "id": "56556523d035cafbdb5dae1b",
    "club_name": "Tekniska Högskolan FC",
    "image_url": "testing url"
  },
  {
    "id": "56556523d035cafbdb5dae1c",
    "club_name": "Tensta IF",
    "image_url": "testing url"
  }

]
```

Comment: You will have to provide the code you use, otherwise how do we debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `NSJSONSerialization` for this. Assuming your string is in a variable called `jsonString`, try the following.

```
let data = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
guard let jsonData = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data ?? NSData(), options: .MutableContainers), arr = jsonData as? NSArray else {
    //Handle possible errors here
    return
}
//Do stuff with the arr variable
print(arr)
```

Comment: @EricD. sorry, I'd copied the code from my app. I'll change it.

Comment: @EricD. Fixed. I'd accidentally made it `dict` because I was using a dictionary in my app, and was used to referring to it as that.